# No cerrar Sidenav Materialize cuando se ejecute un clic por fuera

Tags: javascript, html, css3, materialize

Estoy desarrollando un sidenav usando Materialize CSS el cual funciona muy bien.

Necesito que el `sidenav` no se cierre cuando el usuario de un `click` fuera de la pantalla, por defecto el **sidenav** de **materialize** ya lo hace, pero no encuentro en sus propiedades una que me permita bloquear ese cierre de esa forma.

Ya intente usando la propiedad `dismissible: false, pero no me funciona.

Cualquier aporte me ayudara mucho.

Dejo un ejemplo del sidenav de Materialize.

Gracias.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>
  <ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
    <li>
      <div class="user-view">
        <div class="background">
          <img src="images/office.jpg">
        </div>
        <a href="#user"><img class="circle" src="images/yuna.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
        <a href="#email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
    <li>
      <div class="divider"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
    <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
      var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```